# $routeProvide get the value in URL in the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have this :

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/Customer/:id?', {
        templateUrl: templatePath + 'Customer/Detail.html',
        controller: 'myAngularJsController',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/defaultroute'
    });
```

The URL is : `http://localhost:39765/#/Customer/7`

I'd like get the value (7) in my page `Detail.html`, in an angularJs variable, how can I do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `$routeParams` service into `myAngularJsController` controller and read param by key

```
console.log($routeParams.id);
```